# Javascript returning null data from an api

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following api to fetch data from http://starlord.hackerearth.com/gamesarena
I am trying to access the json there using the following piece of code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Use the XMLHttpRequest to get the content of a file.</h2>
<p>The content is written in JSON format, and can easily be converted into a JavaScript object.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>


  var requestURL = 'http://starlord.hackerearth.com/gamesarena';
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', requestURL);
  request.responseType = 'json';
  request.send();
  var superHeroes = request.response;
  console.log(request.response);
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

I expect to see JSON data,but get null.Can you explain what is missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that's because of you are trying to get content before the response came. All XMLHttpRequests are async by default ( Many browsers will not let you make sync requests btw ). You can get the response content async way like that :

```
  var requestURL = 'http://starlord.hackerearth.com/gamesarena';
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        // response
        console.log(request.response);
    }
  };
  request.open('GET', requestURL);
  request.responseType = 'json';
  request.send();
```

Comment: can you please explain what happens I mean the change.

Comment: As I said in top, you were creating async requests to API, all async methods have to deal result with a callback. In this case our callback is the function that we assigned to `onreadystatechange` . `XMLHttpRequest.DONE` is just for to understand whether request completed successfully or not.

Comment: And other thing is you were trying to get response immediately after sending request to API. You can't know your response is came in that line that's because of your request is not synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `load` event to handle server response:

```
request.addEventListener("load", function(){
    console.log(this.responseText);
});
```

Note that `load` event only fired when the server send response to the client.

Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Use the XMLHttpRequest to get the content of a file.</h2>
<p>The content is written in JSON format, and can easily be converted into a JavaScript object.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>


  var requestURL = 'http://starlord.hackerearth.com/gamesarena';
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', requestURL);
  request.responseType = 'json';
  
  request.addEventListener("load", function(){
      console.log(this.responseText);
  });

  request.send();
</script>


</body>
</html>
```